# Fan / thermal control for Dell M3800 with Debian

Tags: linux, temperature, fan, sensors

I installed Debian 9 Stretch to my Dell Precision M3800 and it works beautifully.... except for thermal control.

If I lshw, I get this:

```
*-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
     description: Signal processing controller
     product: 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.6
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
     version: 05
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:f7a20000-f7a20fff
```

If i run sensors, I get:

```
$ sensors
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 4800 RPM
Video Fan:     4900 RPM
CPU:            +40.0°C 



acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:       -269.2°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.60 V  (min =  +0.60 V, max =  +1.20 V)
temp1:            N/A  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +39.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +38.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +38.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +38.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +38.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

When I run fancontrol, the fans stop completely.  When I exit, fans turn on full throttle.

I have tried running fancontrol, lm-sensors and thermald but nothing seems to regulate fan speed.

I have also run pwmconfig which tries to configure fan settings, but I get:

```
No correlations were detected.
There is either no fan connected to the output of hwmon2/pwm1,
or the connected fan has no rpm-signal connected to one of
the tested fan sensors. (Note: not all motherboards have
the pwm outputs connected to the fan connectors,
check out the hardware database on http://www.almico.com/forumindex.php)
```

Did you see/hear a fan stopping during the above test (n)?

I answer with yes, because fans and I managed to generate an /etc/fancontrol with some values, but it doesn't work.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.